# How to fetch data from hana to R.my codes are showing error

Tags: r, hana

I am **fetching data table to R from hana** but it is showing some kind of error.

Succesfully integrated and odbc got connected but data is not fetching.

```
sqlFetch(ch,'SELECT * FROM "MY_SCHEMA.TICKETS_BY_YEAR"')
```

> Error in odbcTableExists(channel, sqtable) : 
>     ‘SELECT * FROM "MY_SCHEMA.TICKETS_BY_YEAR"’: table not found on channel

i expected for the data but it is not coming

Answer (score 1):

The cause of the error message is the wrong use of double-quotes (“).
To correctly quote the `schema name` and the `table name`, each of them need to be enclosed in a couple of quotation marks like so:

```
   FROM “SCHEMA_NAME”.”TABLE_NAME”
        ^           ^ ^          ^
```

Your command in R needs to look like this:

```
sqlFetch(ch, 'SELECT * FROM "MY_SCHEMA”.”TICKETS_BY_YEAR"')
```

Comment: still now problem persist with the error   Error in sqlFetch(ch, "SELECT * FROM \"MY_SCHEMA”.”TICKETS_BY_YEAR\"") : 
  first argument is not an open RODBC channel

Comment: You will have to open the DB connection before using it to execute commands.

Comment: already i have opened by database connection.please explain in detail.now i am getting this error."42S02 259 [SAP AG][LIBODBCHDB DLL][HDBODBC] Base table or view not found;259 invalid table name:  Could not find table/view TICKETS_BY_YEAR in schema MY_SCHEMA: line 1 col 25 (at pos 24)"
[2] "[RODBC] ERROR: Could not SQLExecDirect 'SELECT*FROM \"MY_SCHEMA\".\"TICKETS_BY_YEAR\"'"

Comment: i have installed rodbc package

Comment: Hi @PRIYA, the original question was correctly answered. The subsequent errors are due to other causes. 
Make sure that the user you use to connect can actually access the table in the schema (`"MY_SCHEMA"` looks suspiciously like a placeholder that has not been replaced with the actual value).  Also be aware that with the double-quotes in place, the schema/tablenames are case-sensitive, so make sure that upper/lower case characters are correct.

Comment: Hi,Is there any need to give access to the  hana  table that we require to extract.please guide me

Comment: please give some insights